# C++ Int getting random value after function that isn't supposed to change it

Tags: c++, random, int

Okay - yes, this is homework, but it isn't mine.  I have a friend taking an introductory C++ course who asked me for help, and I helped them write this program, but there is one weird bug that I can't figure out.  Any helpful suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!!

The following is the code.  The problem is that after the add_loop function, the int loop_size gets a random value.  Within the function, it has the value it is supposed to have, but afterwards, it changes.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
#define STRING_SIZE 50

void get_template (char StemLoop [])
{
    char Template [STRING_SIZE];
    cout<<"Please enter a template for the stem:";
    cin>> Template;
    strcpy (StemLoop, Template);
}

void add_loop (char StemLoop[], int loop_size)
{

    char random_loop [STRING_SIZE];

    int random_array[STRING_SIZE];

    for (int i=0; i<loop_size; i++)
    {
        random_array[i] = rand() % 4;
        if (random_array[i]==0)
            random_loop[i]='A';
        else if (random_array[i]==1)
            random_loop [i]='U';
        else if (random_array[i]==2)
            random_loop [i]='G';
        else if (random_array[i]==3)
            random_loop [i]='C';

    }
    strcat (StemLoop, random_loop);
}

void add_complement(char StemLoop[], int loop_size)
{

    int  x =strlen(StemLoop);
    int j=0;
    char complement [STRING_SIZE]="";
    for (int i=0; i<(x-loop_size); i++)
    {
        if (StemLoop[i]=='A')
            complement[j]='U';
        else if (StemLoop[i]=='U')
            complement[j]='A';
        else if (StemLoop[i]=='G')
            complement[j]='C';
        else if (StemLoop[i]=='C')
            complement[j]='G';
        j++;
    }
    strcat(StemLoop,complement);
}

void main()
{
    int loop_size=0;
    cout<<"Please enter the size of the loop: ";
    cin>>loop_size;

    char StemLoop [STRING_SIZE];

    //Part1: the template
    get_template (StemLoop);

    //This is supposed to be the function that adds the loop of random "genes".
    //It works, and within it the int loop_size is the correct value...
    add_loop (StemLoop, loop_size);
    /*...but here it is a random number.  It's as if the random value generated
    within the function is getting assigned to it.  And of course, it's throwing off the 
    entire program.
    */

    //Part#3: the complement
    add_complement (StemLoop, loop_size);
    cout<<"The complete stem-loop strand is:"<<StemLoop<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What size is the template you're entering.  You almost certainly have a stack overflow somewhere, because you aren't properly checking some limit or other.

Comment: I'm tutoring her.  I didn't "do her homework for her".  And I'm not asking for you to do it either.  Just to help me find one tiny bug.

Comment: (that was in reply to a comment that has since been deleted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not 0-terminating `random_loop` before you use it in `strcat`, so `strcat` can write all over your stack. Try this:

```
random_loop[i] = 0;
strcat (StemLoop, random_loop);
```

A more serious problem could be that you're not checking you have enough room to `strcat`.

Comment: I think the missing 0-termination is the problem here. Keep in mind that arrays are not, by default, filled with zeroes when defined, you must do this by hand (or let the last execution of the for loop terminate the string).